# Can't delete ._Icon from Dropbox in Windows

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I used Dropbox on mac recently and that Synced some files with windows. Now I'm not using a mac anymore and there's a file named `._Icon` that refuses to go away.
I am not able to delete it, nor am I able to rename it.
The error message I get while deleting is `The file name you specified is too long or not valid.`
Here is the directory listing

```
 Directory of D:\Dropbox

20-03-2012  19:46    <DIR>          .
20-03-2012  19:46    <DIR>          ..
08-01-2012  14:18                29 .dropbox
02-10-2011  13:12           291,232 ._Icon
```

How do I get rid of this, It's not a very big file but its presence is irritating.
Also do we have something like gitignore for Dropbox.

See the offending file shown below
[image: This is the file I want to get rid of]

Answer (score 1):

Go to dropbox.com and delete the file from there? It should sync delete them from all computer connected.

Answer (score 0):

The icon file is named on OSX `Icon?` and should not get synchronized to Dropbox (as well as the `._`-files). Nevertheless the file is there and you should get rid of it.

You can try [DelinvFile - Delete Invalid Files and Folders](http://www.purgeie.com/delinv/) to remove it on Windows7.

Comment: I'd prefer a solution that doesn't need me installing any additional software